# MSMQ getBody Exception while listening from MQ

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, msmq

im getting this exception while receiving msgs from queue in a while loop, please guide, i will provide more details if needed.
Thanks

Exception:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Messaging.BinaryMessageFormatter.Read(Message message)
   at System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()
```

CODE:

```
while(true)
{
    string aryRet = "";

    System.Messaging.Message msg = InQueue.Receive();
    aryRet = msg.Body.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You have binary data.  Why are you using ToString()?

Comment: Sending and Receiving both have binaryformatters in MQ format..
like this:

`InQueue.Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter();`

Comment: Why ToString()?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.messaging.binarymessageformatter?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Because both sides are dealing with string..
Sender sending string like `mq.send("SS this is sender");`

hence receiver should convert it into string.

Comment: Good answer.  So You are expecting an array of body?  Do you get through the while loop once without error?  I would think the Receive() should be before the while loop.   Receive() would get entire response.  there may be more than one attachment so you could get multiple bodies.